# Copying from a website into a JTextPane is giving me unwanted formatting and html tags

Tags: java, html, swing, paste, jtextpane

Here is some background information:

I have a class that extends JTextPane that when you copy text from a website into it is giving me unwanted formatting elements and tags. iframes, fonts, etc. The type of JTextPane is html/text and needs to stay this way because I change links to clickable links in another part of my code.

As far as I know it's automatically trying to keep formatting when I copy and paste into the JTextPane from the web, I don't want this to happen.

Some things to keep in mind, I am using HTMLEditorKit and I do not want to add another large tool to my repository. Is there a simple way I can just get the text and not all the elements and formatting to paste with it?

Comment: you can use DefaultEditorKit instead of HTMLEditorKit

Comment: Are there any good methods out there to strip html easily in using this library? I know a lot of people suggest going to an html parser, but I'm trying to avoid adding lots of libraries that will be bulky. I'm trying to avoid re-inventing the wheel on this one.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use DefaultEditorKit, and just want to copy&paste text to HtmlEditorKit, you may try to write your own paste code,

```
textPane.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_V, ActionEvent.CTRL_MASK), "paste");

textPane.getActionMap().put("paste", pasteAction);

class PasteAction extends AbstractAction {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                int offset = textPane.getSelectionStart();
                Document sd=textPane.getDocument();
                String value = getClipboard();
                sd.remove(textPane.getSelectionStart(), textPane.getSelectionEnd()-textPane.getSelectionStart());
                textPane.getDocument().insertString(offset, value , null);
                if (value != null) {
                    textPane.setCaretPosition(offset + value.length());
                }
            } catch (Exception exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

}
```

And use this code to get pure text from your clipboard,

```
public String getClipboard() throws ClassNotFoundException, UnsupportedFlavorException {
    Transferable t = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().getContents(null);
    DataFlavor htmlStringFlavor = new DataFlavor("text/plain; class=java.lang.String");
    try {
        if (t != null && t.isDataFlavorSupported(htmlStringFlavor)) {
            String text = (String) t.getTransferData(htmlStringFlavor);
            return text;
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

If you have menu items, toolbar or other triggers, do not forget to bind "paste" action to them.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to start with :

```
    editorKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
    setEditorKit(editorKit);

    htmlDoc = (HTMLDocument) editorKit.createDefaultDocument();
    htmlDoc.setPreservesUnknownTags(false);
```

Then you can use :

```
    DataFlavor htmlFlavor = new DataFlavor("text/html;class=java.lang.String");

    String html = (String) clipboard.getData(htmlFlavor);
    editorKit.read(new StringReader(html), htmlDoc, 0);
```

I let the rest to yourself. But I really advice you to use JSoup if you're working with HTML. It's very light, very powerful and very useful !